# load two different pages in one. How?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I must have access to both pages normally, or have a control similar to what I could have with selenium but can be controlled entirely by the client without webdrivers or programs to be installed. 
It is possible?  In particular I want load web.whatsapp.com
Sorry for my English.

Comment: you can use `jquery load`

Comment: @ElyasEsna — The same origin policy will prevent it.